# How to show only rows that a field have more than one subject

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically, I want to show the users that have more than one enrolment in the same course. When I tried, I had no success because this is more complicated than I expected, and I have a not so simple scenario (I tried to apply similar cases found here).

I need to show these rows based on other tables, that is, with JOINs.

The query bellow shows only three columns that I need to process with this operation. If it is possible, this query should be part of other JOIN because I’ll need to show other details about the classes.

```
SELECT eseat.USER_ID, c.COURSE_ID, t.CLASS_ID
FROM
    table_CLASS t                                                                       -- Classes
    LEFT JOIN                                                                           -- This JOIN is necessary to have only the future Classes
    (
        SELECT aa.CLASS_ID, MIN(aa.START_DATE) AS "START", MAX(aa.END_DATE) AS "END"
        FROM table_SEG_CLASS aa                                                         -- Segment x Class
        GROUP BY aa.CLASS_ID
    ) seg ON seg.CLASS_ID = t.CLASS_ID
    LEFT JOIN table_ENROLL_CLASS eseat ON eseat.CLASS_ID = t.CLASS_ID                   -- Enrollment x Class
    LEFT JOIN table_ENROLL_STAT estat ON estat.ENRL_STAT_ID = eseat.ENRL_STAT_ID        -- Enrollment status type
    LEFT JOIN table_COURSE c ON c.COURSE_ID = t.COURSE_ID                               -- Course x Class

WHERE
    1=1
    AND t.CANCELLED = 'N'               -- Only active classes
    AND estat.ENRL_STAT_TYP_ID <> 'C'   -- Not show cancelled enrollment status
    AND SYSDATE <= "END"                -- To show only future classes
```

Bellow, the fields of these tables.

**[table_CLASS]**

```
CLASS_ID | COURSE_ID
T_0001   | C_0001
T_0002   | C_0001
T_0101   | C_0002
T_0201   | C_0003
T_0301   | C_0004
...
```

**[table_SEG_CLASS]**

```
CLASS_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE
T_0001   | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-02
T_0002   | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-02 
T_0101   | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-02
T_0201   | 2019-04-01 | 2019-04-02
T_0301   | 2019-05-01 | 2019-05-02
...
```

**[table_ENROLL_CLASS]**

```
USER_ID | CLASS_ID | ENRL_STAT_ID
00001   | T_0001   | ENROLL
00001   | T_0002   | ENROLL
00001   | T_0101   | ENROLL
00001   | T_0201   | ENROLL
00001   | T_0301   | ENROLL
00002   | T_0001   | ENROLL
00002   | T_0101   | ENROLL
00002   | T_0201   | ENROLL
00002   | T_0301   | ENROLL
...
```

**[table_ENROLL_STAT]**

```
ENRL_STAT_ID | ENRL_STAT_TYP_ID
ENROLL       | E
CANCELLED    | C
WAITLIST     | W
...
```

**[table_COURSE]**

```
COURSE_ID | COURSE_NAME
C_0001    | Course 01
C_0002    | Course 02
C_0003    | Course 03
C_0004    | Course 04
...
```

**OUTPUT**

```
USER_ID | COURSE_ID | CLASS_ID
00001   | C_0001    | T_0001
00001   | C_0001    | T_0002
00001   | C_0002    | T_0101
00001   | C_0003    | T_0201
00001   | C_0004    | T_0301
00002   | C_0001    | T_0001
00002   | C_0002    | T_0101
00002   | C_0003    | T_0201
00002   | C_0004    | T_0301
```

**EXPETED OUTPUT**

```
USER_ID | COURSE_ID | CLASS_ID
00001   | C_0001    | T_0001
00001   | C_0001    | T_0002
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID, COURSE_ID) AS cnt` to your existing query, put it in a Derived Table (Inline View) and apply `WHERE cnt > 1`.

Comment: @dnoeth,fantastic! Easy and simple!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. I'd normally use EXISTS, but since you have a bunch of joins I'll stick with that.

```
SELECT eseat.USER_ID, c.COURSE_ID, t.CLASS_ID
FROM
    table_CLASS t                                                                       -- Classes
    LEFT JOIN                                                                           -- This JOIN is necessary to have only the future Classes
    (
        SELECT aa.CLASS_ID, MIN(aa.START_DATE) AS "START", MAX(aa.END_DATE) AS "END"
        FROM table_SEG_CLASS aa                                                         -- Segment x Class
        GROUP BY aa.CLASS_ID
    ) seg ON seg.CLASS_ID = t.CLASS_ID
    LEFT JOIN table_ENROLL_CLASS eseat ON eseat.CLASS_ID = t.CLASS_ID                   -- Enrollment x Class
    LEFT JOIN table_ENROLL_STAT estat ON estat.ENRL_STAT_ID = eseat.ENRL_STAT_ID        -- Enrollment status type
    LEFT JOIN table_COURSE c ON c.COURSE_ID = t.COURSE_ID                               -- Course x Class
-- added this line: user is also enrolled in a different class for this course
    inner join table_enroll_class eseat2 on eseat2.user_id = eseat.user_id 
        and eseat2.class_id in (select class_id from table_class where course_id = t.course_id and class_id <> eseat.class_id)
WHERE
    1=1
    AND t.CANCELLED = 'N'               -- Only active classes
    AND estat.ENRL_STAT_TYP_ID <> 'C'   -- Not show cancelled enrollment status
    AND SYSDATE <= "END"                -- To show only future classes
```

I think you probably also want "eseat" to be an inner join, but that's just a clarity issue.

Comment: I could not get the expected result applying this. I applied `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID, COURSE_ID)` like @dnoeth proposed.